# How to combine two seperate Mongo aggregations into one aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two aggregation query's which I want to combine into a single aggregation query. I am wondering how I can achieve this.

Both query's are talking about a collection called `Submission` which mainly is about the `status`. Below are the two aggregation query's
:

[Aggregation 1: Submissions grouped by the Booking ID all have the status SUCCESS](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D4SAlDJPuZm)

[Aggregation 2: Submissions grouped by the Booking ID have at least one with status ERROR](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L25ErwgZVNU)

Ideally what I would like is the following outcome:

```
{
    "_id": null,
    "successBookingIds": [
      "NW111"
    ],
    "errorBookingIds": [
      "NW115"
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve this in the best possible way? Taking performance into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this use case using [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) stage

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      sent: false
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$bookingId",
      status: {
        $addToSet: "$status"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      success: [
        {
          $match: {
            status: {
              $nin: [
                "ERROR"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            status: {
              $in: [
                "SUCCESS"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            success: "$_id",
            _id: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      error: [
        {
          $match: {
            status: {
              $in: [
                "ERROR"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            error: "$_id",
            _id: 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      concat: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$error",
          "$success"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$concat"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      successBookingIds: {
        $push: "$concat.success"
      },
      errorBookingIds: {
        $push: "$concat.error"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[See Working query in MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YEGKswNH9xR)